# Different behaviours with different browsers for oninput event in input type time

Tags: javascript, html, events, input, browser

I'm trying to apply some control on a 24 hours format input type time (min and max time allowed and only 00 and 30 minutes) using the oninput event.
With Firefox is fantastic because it applies controls only after the end of the 2 digits for hours and minutes, but in Chrome the event is triggered as soon I put the first digit, so I can't insert anything because if I want to insert 15, it start to control on 1.
Someone else had similar experience or knows how to do similar controls?.
Below is the function I'm using. Thanks

```
function timectrl() {
    var mytime = document.getElementById("ora").value;
    var sommaora = new Date();
    var initialtime = "<?= $_POST['oraini'] ?>";
    var finaltime = "<?= $_POST['orafine'] ?>";

    mytime = mytime.split(":");
    initialtime = orini.split(":");
    finaltime = orfine.split(":");

    sommaora.setHours(mytime[0],mytime[1]);
    if ((mytime[1]>00) && (mytime[1]<=15))  
    {
      document.getElementById("ora").value=sommaora.getHours()+":00";
    }
    else if ((mytime[1]>15) && (mytime[1]<=30))  
    {
      document.getElementById("ora").value=sommaora.getHours()+":30";
    }
    else if ((mytime[1]>30) && (mytime[1]<=45))  
    {
      document.getElementById("ora").value=sommaora.getHours()+":30";
    }
    else if ((mytime[1]>45) && (mytime[1]<=60))  
    {
      document.getElementById("ora").value=sommaora.getHours()+":00";
    }

    if (mytime[0]<initialtime[0])  
    {
       document.getElementById("ora").value=initialtime[0]+":"+initialtime[1];
    }
    if (mytime[0]>finaltime[0])  
    {
      document.getElementById("ora").value=finaltime[0]+":"+finaltime[1];
    }


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the beginning of your logic:

```
function timectrl() {
    var mytime = document.getElementById("ora").value;
    var reduced = mytime.split(":").slice(0,2)
       .reduce(function(ac,d,i){
             return ac+= i ? +d : 60*(d%12)
        },0);
    if(
       Math.max(0,Math.min(30,reduced)) !== reduced
    ){
       return
    }
    var sommaora = new Date();
    var initialtime = "<?= $_POST['oraini'] ?>";
    var finaltime = "<?= $_POST['orafine'] ?>";
.....
```

Not exactly sure if this is what you are asking but a fiddle would help

Comment: Thanks. but the format is hh:ii so the length is always 2

Comment: There is no fiddle so I cannot check the behavior, in that case check my updated proposal

Comment: sorry :/ I'm new...what is fiddle? :D
Anyway I tried but nothing change..

Comment: I changed the 1800 made it 30

Comment: Not completely but now is better and I can workaround :) I'll try later and I'll post the solution. thank you very much!

Comment: Next time try a fiddle or something like it (https://fiddle.jshell.net/), it makes life easier for everybody. Probably you should have used a focus and blur events instead of correcting on every input..But I cannot see the application.

Answer (score 0):

In html5 the `<input type="time">` element has an attribute `step` that should do exactly what has been discussed in this post. The step is entered as seconds, so 30 minutes are 1800 seconds. Unfortunately not many browsers actually carry out the input rounding as specified by this attribute. The following "polyfill" takes care of this shortcoming: whenever an input has been made the value of that element gets rounded to the nearest time-value fulfilling the `step` attribute. In my example I bind the action to the `input`-event of the element:

```js
$('input[type=time]').change(ev=>{var e=ev.target;
 if(e.step){
  var ti=e.value.split(':'),st=e.step/60,
  mi=Math.round(ti[1]/st)*st,
  ho=(ti[0]-0)+Math.floor(mi/60);
  mi=mi%60;ho=ho%24;
  e.value=('0'+ho).substr(-2)+':'+('0'+mi).substr(-2);
}});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="time">
 <label>15 min. steps:
 <input type="time" name="start" step="900"></label><br>
 <label>30 min. steps:</label>
 <input type="time" name="end" step="1800">
</form>
```